# How can I open an image with a Python script in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

In the script editor in Blender 2.79 on Windows, I can open an image with:

`bpy.ops.image.open(filepath="C:\\path\\to\\image.png")`

However, if I put this code in a .py file and open Blender from the command line (git bash, in this case), passing the .py file with a `--python` flag, Blender crashes:

> Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

What's up here?

Comment: Can you show exactly all what you run in that script which gives you that error? I tried on linux, and it seems to work.

Comment: Details are in the bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T53446

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, it works in Blender 2.78c – I've reported it here: https://developer.blender.org/T53446

Update: Fixed in 2.79a: https://developer.blender.org/rB5b3c15e3363aa7bea5d26c56191b7e8e74021868